# Monitor network traffic "during a specific time" in linux

Tags: networking

I need to measure network usage on a specific interface during a specific time. I'm doing some experiments on an application so I need to know how much data is being passed around on a specific interface. So things go like:

```
1- start recording network usage
2- start the program
3- end the program
4- stop recording network usage
```

I know tools like [vnstat](http://humdi.net/vnstat/man/vnstat.html) and [nload](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nload) exist, but they don't seem to have the feature I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `vnstat -l` does do what you need

Simply open a terminal window and type `vnstat -l`. Then start your program that consumes network bandwidth. When your program ends return to the terminal window and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. The terminal will then show time elapsed and network traffic consumed:

```
$ vnstat -l
Monitoring enp59s0...    (press CTRL-C to stop)

   rx:     1.74 Mbit/s   149 p/s          tx:       32 kbit/s    62 p/s^C


 enp59s0  /  traffic statistics

                           rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                     7.40 MiB  |         142 KiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max            1.84 Mbit/s  |       35 kbit/s
      average            1.68 Mbit/s  |    31.53 kbit/s
          min            1.51 Mbit/s  |       29 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                       5215  |            2187
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max                157 p/s  |          68 p/s
      average                144 p/s  |          60 p/s
          min                129 p/s  |          55 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                    36 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Somehow I managed to miss this, just how I can log it into a file and stop it if I'm doing this in a script? (other than killing it)

Comment: @Manuel If you are calling it in a script then you would use `vnstat -q > starttotal` at start of your script. Do your processing then use `vnstat -q > endtotal`. Then parse the two output files to calculate `endtotal` - `starttotal` = `bytesused`.